# GridView - Editable ComboBox Data become slow

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, gridview, combobox, dropdown

this is the code which i custom the column in gridview to show the data. i try to get the data from editable text that i type from comboBox, but the data output become too slow to appear in list

```
 settings.Columns.Add(column =>
    {
        column.FieldName = "Food";
        column.Caption = "Food List";
        column.Width = 350;
        column.ColumnType = MVCxGridViewColumnType.ComboBox;
        var comboBoxProperties = column.PropertiesEdit as ComboBoxProperties;
       comboBoxProperties.Width = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit(350);
        comboBoxProperties.DataSource = Food.Shared.ListFood;   
        comboBoxProperties.TextField = "Value";
        comboBoxProperties.ValueField = "Key";
       comboBoxProperties.ValueType = typeof(Guid);
       comboBoxProperties.IncrementalFilteringMode = IncrementalFilteringMode.Contains;
        comboBoxProperties.ItemStyle.Wrap = DefaultBoolean.True;
       comboBoxProperties.ClientInstanceName = "foodListTo";
    });
```

Comment: Can you explain what things which implies "too slow"? Also some details still missing (including `Food.Shared.ListFood` property), please include them in your question.

Comment: the data filter is too slow, when i type, the data load too slow. its because the data is too big

Comment: the filter part work fine and faster if the datasorce is not much